How should I pass a map subtype into a function?
  void foo() {
    final fooMap = {
      'one': true,
    };
    bar(fooMap);
  }

  void bar(Map<String, Object> barMap) {
    barMap['two'] = 'Hello World';
  }

In the above code, I get the error:
DartError: TypeError: "Hello World": type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
As I understand it, this is because Map<String, bool> is not a subtype of Map<String, Object>. If my understanding is correct, I don't know why my IDE doesn't tell me not to do that.
In foo(), if I change final fooMap... to Map<String, Object> fooMap..., then everything works just fine. But again, I feel like the IDE should catch it, to let me know about this.
In bar(), if I copy the map into a new Map<String, Object>, it also works.
My question is, how should I handle this? Is there a strongly typed option here? I prefer to catch things like this at compile time, not runtime.

Map<String,Object> is the formal arg type.  It can be narrowed depending on the actual value passed in, in this case a Map<String,bool>, which will trigger a runtime error when you try to use a wider key type, which you did.  If you need barMap to be a Map<String,String>, then say that in your formal arg, and your caller would then have been properly flagged.

@RandalSchwartz i dont need it to be Map<String, String>.  I need it to be Map<String, dynamic> or Map<String, Object>.  It has unknown types coming in, and i need to add a string to it in bar(). I figured having the parameter type being Map<String, dynamic> or Map<String, Object> would make that clear to the compiler, but it does not.

But an existing Map<String,bool> cannot have an element added that has a String value.  It cannot.  And you're getting a runtime error for that.  You can trap that error using an "is" or pattern match or a try/catch.

@RandalSchwartz So there is no way to catch it at compile time?

Not without narrowing the formal arg to Map<String,String>

For better of for worse, Dart allows Generic<Derived> to be a subtype of Generic<Base> if Derived is a subtype of Base.  Usually this is convenient, but it can lead to cases like this. bar(fooMap) and barMap['two'] = 'Hello World' are each perfectly legal in isolation; there is nothing the IDE can do to protect you from this because the problem is a runtime error.

Dart's type inference is strong; the Map s type will be inferred by its entries.
final map = {
  'one': true,
};

is the same as
final Map<String, bool> map = {
  'one': true,
};

You don't get a compile error for the bar function because technically, the map's type of Map<String, bool> compiles with the parameter's type of Map<String, Object>.
In Dart, as everything is of type Object (except null).
final one = true;
print(one is Object); // true

If you would like to allow dynamic values on your map, you can go about it a couple different ways.

(Recommended) Supply type arguments to the map

final map = <String, dynamic>{
  'one': true,
};


Add a second entry that differs from the first entries type

final map = {
  'one': true,
  'two': 'hello world',
};

Caution: This way only works because you are providing multiple values of different types.
If you provided multiple entries of the same types, the map's inferred type wouldn't change
// type: Map<String, bool>
final map = {
  'one': true,
  'two': false,
};

